# Automatic conversion between .ps to .pdf upon download onto Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, pdf, postscript, automator

Is there any way to convert `.ps` to `.pdf` every time automatically as a `.ps` is downloaded onto a Mac machine? (Using Mountain Lion 10.8)

- can Automator perform this task?
- convert and then delete the `.ps`

It's annoying that it has to convert from `.ps` to `.pdf` in preview every time I open the file, and quick preview doesn't work on `.ps`.

Comment: Probably better suited to http://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks. I posted there and got [answered](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163668/automatic-conversion-between-ps-to-pdf-upon-download-onto-mac-osx/163675#163675).